# How to diff one file to an arbitrary version in Git?

Tags: git, diff, git-diff

How can I diff a file, say `pom.xml`, from the master branch to an arbitrary older version in Git?

Answer (score 455, accepted):

You can do:

```
git diff master~20:pom.xml pom.xml
```

... to compare your current `pom.xml` to the one from `master` 20 revisions ago through the first parent.  You can replace `master~20`, of course, with the object name (SHA1sum) of a commit or any of the [many other ways of specifying a revision](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html#_specifying_revisions).

Note that this is actually comparing the old `pom.xml` to the version in your working tree, not the version committed in `master`.  If you want that, then you can do the following instead:

```
git diff master~20:pom.xml master:pom.xml
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't just work for files, it also works for (sub)directories as well, for example `git diff <revision>:foo/ HEAD:foo/`.

Comment: Also note that on windows you need to use forward slashes for directories if you are using a revision specifier or git will give you an error about the file/directory not existing in that revision.

Comment: @DylanNissley or it will give you no error and no diff. That's what I see. In any case, thank you for the hint about using forward slashes instead of backslashes.

Comment: With windows files I've found it easier to change directory and then call git diff master~20:./pom.xml ./pom.xml

Comment: Some version of git require "--" between the <revision> & <path>

Answer (score 191):

```
git diff <revision> <path>
```

For example:

```
git diff b0d14a4 foobar.txt
```

Comment: does not work for version 1.7.11 if file is not in current directory. Example: 'git diff f76d078 test/Config' yields "error: Could not access 'test/f76d078'"

Comment: @user1663987 just pass a full path relative to the project root: `git diff <revision> root/path/file`.

Comment: test/Config *is* relative to the root (as in test is a sub-directory of the root). but then your example root/path/file would seem to INCLUDE the root?

Answer (score 58):

If you want to see the difference between the last commit of a single file you can do:

```
git log -p -1 filename
```

This will give you the diff of the file in git, is not comparing your local file.

Comment: this is not returning anything

Comment: @AndreiCristianProdan Then you have no changes there. You can increment the `-1` step by step until you get the changes.

Comment: This is very nice. I created a bash function that might be useful:

`gitlog () { git log -${3:-p} -${2:-1} $1; }`

Used like: `gitlog Rakefile` or `gitlog Rakefile 5` and `gitlog Rakefile 10 s`. The first shows one diff; the second shows five diffs; the third shows ten `--no-patch`.

Comment: works just fine with WSL Ubuntu 20.04 LTS running on Windows 11.

Answer (score 51):

To see what was changed in a file in the last commit:

```
git diff HEAD~1 -- path/to/file
```

You can change the number (~1) to the n-th commit which you want to diff with.

Comment: This answer is really just a specific case of [this more general answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5586434/456814), where `HEAD~1` is substituted for `<revision>`, which makes this answer a duplicate.

Comment: this isn't working!
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD~1': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions

Comment: This answer is simple and functional for me.

Comment: "--" separator is missing, I have just fixed

Comment: This works better for me! using WSL Ubuntu 20.04 LTS running on Windows 11.

Answer (score 11):

```
git diff -w HEAD origin/master path/to/file
```

-w ignores whitespaces

Comment: You could at least give some explanation as to what the -w flag means. Writing a solution that works is great, but I personally wouldn't use some random command without knowing what each flag in it means.

Comment: @TalKohavy You are right, I wrote that in a hurry, I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 11):

**Generic Syntax :**

```
$git diff oldCommit..newCommit -- **FileName.xml > ~/diff.txt
```

for all files named "FileName.xml" anywhere in your repo.

Notice the space between "--" and "**"

**Answer for your question:**

```
$git checkout master
$git diff oldCommit..HEAD -- **pom.xml 
or
$git diff oldCommit..HEAD -- relative/path/to/pom.xml
```

as always with git, you can use a tag/sha1/"HEAD^" to id a commit.

Tested with git 1.9.1 on Ubuntu.

Comment: too verbose, almost useless.

Answer (score 8):

If neither commit is your HEAD then bash's **brace expansion** proves really useful, especially if your filenames are long, the example above:

```bash
git diff master~20:pom.xml master:pom.xml
```

Would become

```bash
git diff {master~20,master}:pom.xml
```

More on [Brace expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace) with bash.

Answer (score 7):

For comparing to 5 commit to the current one, both on `master`, just simply do:

```
git diff master~5:pom.xml master:pom.xml
```

Also you can refer to commit hash number, for example if the hash number is `x110bd64`, you can do something like this to  see the difference:

```
git diff x110bd64 pom.xml
```

Answer (score 3):

```
git diff master~20 -- pom.xml
```

Works if you are not in master branch too.

Answer (score 2):

If you are fine using a graphical tool (or even prefer it) you can:

```
gitk pom.xml
```

In gitk you can then click any commit (to "select" it) and right click any other commit to select "Diff this -> selected" or "Diff selected -> this" in the popup menu, depending on what order you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

For people interested in doing the same from GitHub, see [comparing commits across time](https://help.github.com/articles/comparing-commits-across-time/).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to diff on a single file in a stash for example you can do

```
git diff stash@{0} -- path/to/file
```

Answer (score 1):

lets say you want to diff the file `interrupt.c` located in `firmware/src/`

---

### **difftool between working area (what yet to be committed or staged) and latest commit:**

> git difftool head firmware/src/interrupt.c

or

> git difftool head *interrupt.c

Note: to diff x versions before the last committed version replace "head" with head~x. For example replace "head" with "head~2" to diff between working area and 2 versions prior to the latest commit

---

### **difftool between two specific committed versions:**

first get the ids for the versions you want to compare by using next line

> git log --oneline

you will get a list of all your committed version. choose two and copy their id's.

[image]

enter the ids inside `{}`:

> git difftool {2fae9e6,a21dd00} firmware/src/interrupt.c

or

> git difftool {2fae9e6,a21dd00} *interrupt.c

Note: if there is no difference between the files, nothing will open. You will just get an empty line in the git bash

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the diff on a specific commit and you want to use the github UI instead of the command line (say you want to link it to other folks), you can do:

```
https://github.com/<org>/<repo>/commit/<commit-sha>/<path-to-file>
```

For example:

https://github.com/grails/grails-core/commit/02942c5b4d832b856fbc04c186f1d02416895a7e/grails-test-suite-uber/build.gradle

Note the Previous and Next links at the top right that allow you to navigate through all the files in the commit.

This only works for a specific commit though, not for comparing between any two arbitrary versions.