# Xcode : IPA File become smaller and won't launch in the device

Tags: xcode

I have a problem that I really don't know where to look.

Before this, the IPA file that distributed from my project archive has a size of 2.4 Mb.
But, after my colleague messing around with the project setting. The IPA file I just built has a size of 990 Kb.
The only thing that different besides the project setting is one of the asset was removed, it has size of 384Kb.

Now, The compile IPA file can't launch on the ad hoc device.

Anyone know where to look or what should be the cause of the problem.

Thank, best regards.

**Edit 1**

I revert all changes to previous git commit, problem still remains.

Comment: Can you revert to the previous version of the project file?

Comment: Yes, I can. I use git to keep tracking the project status. But, it will be great if I don't have to

Comment: Rename both, the old and the new IPA to .zip, extract them and compare the content.

Answer (score 0):

See the SO thread [*How to diff one file to an arbitrary version*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5586435/643383) to learn how to use git's `diff` command to compare your project file to the one you've checked in. I don't claim to be a git expert, but it looks like you should be able to do:

```
git diff master:ProjectFile.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj ProjectFile.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
```

to compare the checked in version against the version in your working directory. The `project.pbxproj` file is an XML file that specifies all the project settings, so comparing the two should tell you exactly what has changed. You may need to go back more than one revision if you're not sure when the change in question was made.

Similarly, you can pull a previous version of your entire project into a new working directory. Build that version and check the size of the .ipa file and see if it'll install.