# search difference between two git branches

Tags: git

I am on a large revamping project, and I would like to see how a specific interface has changed between the current Git branch and the `develop` branch. My ideal operation would be to use some keyword search to look for difference. Using `git diff` does not make sense because of the amount of change which has occurred between the two branches. Any ideas how I can do this effectively?

Comment: STRONG SUGGESTION: Download and familiarize yourself with [Tortoise Git](https://tortoisegit.org/download/), if you're not already using it.

Comment: How do you want to limit the output of `git diff`?  If you want to look at changes to a specific set of files, that's easy to do.  How would a keyword search work?

Comment: Is [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586383/how-to-diff-one-file-to-an-arbitrary-version-in-git) what you need?

Comment: @Prihex More like the entire repo because there are multiple files needed to be compared together at the same time, but that is helpful! Thanks